# Unable to cast object of type 'TextmlBatchDeleteDocument' to 'System.String'

Tags: c#, casting

I am running into an issue that I have never encountered before with type casting.

I am trying to cast an object of type TextmlBatchDeleteDocument to System.String so I implemented an explicit type conversion operator to handle accomplish this.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", this.Collection, this.Name);
}

public static explicit operator string(TextmlBatchDeleteDocument doc)
{
    return doc.ToString();
}
```

Success, the following works.

```
TextmlBatchDeleteDocument doc = new TextmlBatchDeleteDocument("name", "/collection/");
string someString = (string)doc;
```

However I am passing an object of type `List<TextmlBatchDeleteDocument>` to a third party function that requires an object to implement `IList` and it will eventually use the objects in the list as strings.  This is where I run into trouble.  I get this exception whenever I try to call the third party function.

> Unable to cast object of type 'NWDA_Common.Textml.TextmlBatchDeleteDocument' to type 'System.String'.

If my assumptions are correct I am passing the function an object of type `List<TextmlBatchDeleteDocument>` but it gets cast to `IList` which will then treat any object in my list as the base type `System.Object`.  I did a test to confirm this theory and got the same exception.  If I cast my object of type `List<TextmlBatchDeleteDocument>` to `System.Object` first then try to do a cast to a string it will throw an exception.

```
TextmlBatchDeleteDocument doc = new TextmlBatchDeleteDocument("name", "/collection/");
object docAsObj = doc;
string someString = (string)docAsObj;
```

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem or am I stuck with re-factoring and finding another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the third party component *really* needs an `IList` where each element is a string - so that's what you'll need to provide it with. Conversions aren't applied polymorphically - it's a compile-time choice based on the compile-time type of the source expression.

Basically, you'll need to perform the conversion yourself for each element, and pass a list of the converted items to the third party code.

Comment: That's what I expected to hear, I was just hoping there was trick to it.

Comment: So would I be right to conclude that once the object is cast to System.Object it loses any operators defined in the child class

Comment: @Wade: The operators don't belong to the object - they belong to the type. They're static, called non-virtually. It's the same as the difference between Equals (a virtual method, called polymorphically) and == (static, not called polymorphically).

Comment: That makes sense now that I think about it in terms of a static method.  Thanks for your help.